# When using read.csv, why is entire row converted to <NA> is first value in row is <NA>

Tags: r, csv, import

I've using the following `read.csv` command to read in a csv data file containing only 1,540 rows of data. For some reason if the first field in a row is empty then the entire row is returned as NA as shown below.

```
data =  read.csv(full_path, header = TRUE, sep = ",", strip.white = TRUE, 
                     fill = TRUE, na.strings = c('NA','','NULL','#N/A'), 
                     row.names = NULL, blank.lines.skip = TRUE)
```

The file contains 5 useful fields followed by 365 fields which I remove. A sample of the file is shown below:

```
id,conm,No Data,Ticker,Cusip,,,,,,,,,,,
001010-01,ACF INDUSTRIES HOLDING CORP,TRUE,,00099V004^,,,,,,,,,,,
001040-01,AMF INC,TRUE,AMF,001688100^,,,,,,,,,,,
.
.
002444-01,BRUNSWICK CORP,TRUE,BC,117043109^,,,,,,,,,,,
,BURLINGTON INDUSTRIES INC,TRUE,121693972,121693972^,,,,,,,,,,,
002490-01,BURLINGTON NORTHERN INC.,TRUE,BNI,12189T104^,,,,,,,,,,,
```

So in the above CSV sample the data for company 'BURLINGTON INDUSTRIES INC' is lost as the id is empty.

```
 id                                     conm ticker     cusip 
2 001010-01              ACF INDUSTRIES HOLDING CORP   <NA> 00099V004   
3 001040-01                                  AMF INC    AMF 001688100   
4 001045-01                              AMR CORP/DE  AAMRQ 001765106   
.
.
80   002444-01                                BRUNSWICK CORP     BC 117043109   
NA        <NA>                                          <NA>   <NA>      <NA> 
82   002490-01                      BURLINGTON NORTHERN INC.    BNI 12189T104
```

I haven't found this behaviour documented, but is this supposed to happen? There are other fields which are empty but this behaviour doesn't occur. I first tried it without `'row.names = NULL'` and `'blank.lines.skip = TRUE'` and has the same effect.

If I remove the trailing 365 fields from the file, then the read works as expected. I have checked the number of fields trailing the rows and each one contains the same number.

Thanks for your help.

** UPDATE **

I made a mistake, the error wasn't in the read.csv but in the line of code following it as outlined in the answer below.

Comment: When I copy your sample data and paste/save it to a text file in Windows, `read.csv(...)` works (5 lines input, all the Burlington data present). So I'm inclined to think the problem's to do with your csv file. How did you generate it? Can you provide a link to the file, or at least the first 85 lines or so? I've had problems like this with files downloaded from Google docs.

Comment: @jlhoward Yes, you are right the problem was with the next line of code. I thought that I'd checked the state immediately after the read, but I hadn't. I was using a logical check on NA values to remove a line. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the error doesn't occur on the `read.csv` but when I try to remove rows based on values in the id field.

```
data <- data[!data$id == 'Delete-Row',]
```

If `data$id` is `NULL` then a row of `NULL` is returned.

Comment: NA values aren't evaluated as logical statements in most of the situations. At one point you try `NA == "Delete-Row` which equals to `NA` and so the whole row becomes `NA`. Which is your problem? You probably need to use the following logical statement: `data$id != "Delete-Row" | !is.na(data$conm)`

Comment: @Xachriel Yes that was exactly the problem. As you suggested I just added a new condition including the 'NA' case: data <-  data[(is.na(data$id) | !data$id == 'Delete-Row'),]